# GSON DTO Serialize Is Empty

Tags: gson

```
    @Bean
    public GsonBuilder gsonBuilder(List <GsonBuilderCustomizer> customizers) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        customizers.forEach((c) -> c.customize(builder));
        builder
                .serializeNulls()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

}
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ModelStepInfo {

    public boolean isSuccessed;
    public String description;
    public LocalDateTime startTime;
    public LocalDateTime endTime;
}
gson.toJson(new ModelStepInfo(false, "dasdsada", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now()))
```

print: {}
version: 2.10.1
Why does it come out as empty?
Any solution?
I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using [`excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()), but none of your fields have the `@Expose` annotation, so all of them are ignored.